# Virtual GND resistor dividor vs zener diode

Tags: operational-amplifier, zener

I was having a discussion with someone about using a virtual gnd for an opamp circuit.  One way to provide the VCC/2 voltage is with a voltage divider made of two precision resistors (and a capacitor for stability).   Another suggestion was to use a resistor and a zener to set it.

Which method is better, or if that's not a valid question what are the merits of each method.  I would think with resistors of tight tolerance I could approach the accuracy of the zener method.  Also I'd think the zener method would mean if my VCC dipped, or I was on a battery that the voltage would not stay at VCC/2 but rather the zener voltage.

I couldn't think of any pros for the zener column.

Comment: I might be missing the point here but you write first about establishing a virtual ground, about VCC/2 reference, and then again about a zener voltage. What exactly are you trying to do? Drive an op-amp from a single supply with +-VCC/2 supply rails?

Comment: You likely don't need precision resistors.  If you are considering a zener as a possible choice, that pretty much confirms you don't need precisely V/2.

Answer (score 6):

The zener method will generally have a much lower source impedance, so if you're demanding that the virtual ground source or sink more than leakage current you might have more inadvertent coupling through the virtual ground than is tolerable.

For example, if you are willing to use 20mA from a 12V supply to create the virtual ground you can use two 300 ohm resistors in series, so the source impedance will be 150 ohms.

Put the same 20mA into a zener (for example a 1N753A) and the maximum source impedance will be 7 ohms, more than 20x better. The improvement would be similar for lower currents, but that happens to be where the zener is specified.

Of course if you really just want to split the rails down the middle and need to sink or source current, it's possible to use resistors and then buffer the resulting voltage, or use a rail splitter chip with incorporates a buffer.

Note that a single capacitor on the resistor divider will cause asymmetric response to noise or ripple on the supply in a similar way to the zener. In some cases it might be better to use two equal value capacitors.

It really depends on all the requirements which of many possible methods is best (or whether it would be better to generate a true bipolar supply).

Comment: When you say two equal value capacitors you mean one between VCC/2 and GND and one between VCC/2 and VCC?

Comment: @confused. Yes, mirroring the resistor values and in parallel with the resistors- so if you had a 1V ripple on top of the Vcc supply the Vcc/2 point would see 0.5V ripple.

Answer (score 3):

The precision resistor divider is a better way to go than the zener diode. However a lot depends upon what kind of load impedance the divider will have. Too low of load impedance means lowering the divider resistors and consuming a lot of current.

My favorite way to solve this is to use the divider resistors that consume low current but then buffer the resultant divider with an opamp in a voltage follower configuration. This will give you a nice low impedance virtual ground out of the opamp.

Answer (score 3):

You already pretty much described the answer.

A voltage divider will follow the battery voltage and maintain the virtual ground at about half the battery voltage.  You would also add either a bypass / bulk-storage capacitor or an op-amp configured as a follower (or both).  The op-amp buffer makes the virtual ground "stiff", meaning that it doesn't bounce around as you either pull current from it or push current into it.  It also has the benefit of allowing you to use high-value resistors for the voltage divider to reduce power consumption.

A resistor - Zener combination gives you a virtual ground that is already fairly stiff.  You still want a bypass cap / bulk-storage cap but you don't need the op-amp.

There are a couple of disadvantages with the Zener approach.  These are:

1) the virtual ground voltage doesn't track the incoming supply.  That means that you might run out of headroom if the supply dips too low.

2) the Zener is always consuming current.  This increases power consumption.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,.. That is very much valid question that many designs consider it as an option in place of dual power source. Resistors, zener, capacitors, and the combination of them all works fine, but depends on other factors.
Using voltage reference gives more stable voltage, while can be used for reference voltage as well. Important part is that how much current can it source, and how much voltage variation loading causes. This may decide whether to go back to dual power source or not. A certain amount of variation can be covered by PSRR.
However, though depending on the purpose of the circuitry, when it is called as "vertual ground" (this is not proper name for this circuitry) it probably mean "absolute reference to the measurement. Otherwise, it could mealy mean having a convenient "bias".  As others say, using spare buffer(s) is one of the solution to simplify parts count, while drawing less current, but allowing more loading.