# Single voltage power supply to +/- rails

Tags: power-supply, power, signal-integrity

I have a wall wart coming into my circuit in the DC barrel jack shown in the picture. I want to have a positive and negative rail for my op amps as I am unsure of the effect of biasing my signal lines.

Is this how it would be done?

Or should I just bias my signal lines to sit at 10v and have my op amps opperate at 20 and 0 v.

Is there any real difference in a coupled output?

Thanks

[image: wall wart to +/- rail]

Comment: GND and 10V are at the same potential.

Answer (score 4):

That won't work. You have a short-circuit across C1 and R1 so your circuit will give you 0 / 0 / -20 V instead of 10 / 0 / -10 V.

[image]

*Figure 1. Remove the link 'X'.*

The next problem is that the ground is very weakly defined as the 47 kΩ resistors won't have a very good "pull" against any current demands in the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFlEDv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. A Zener regulated supply.*

A Zener regulated supply would be better.

Suggested reading: [Virtual GND resistor dividor vs zener diode](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/157890/virtual-gnd-resistor-dividor-vs-zener-diode).

Answer (score 1):

As drawn your schematic will not split the 20V rail to produce a virtual ground at the center point.  Instead you need to break the connection shown here by the red X.

[image]

Once you break that connection the two 47K resistors will produce a half input voltage virtual ground. It will be stable if there is no current flow on the virtual ground connection. Any current flow in the virtual ground will imbalance the voltage divider accordingly. This is why this method of preparing a virtual ground is so crappy. If you must do it because you are not prepared to make the virtual ground by a better technique that select the two resistor values so that the current flow through the divider branch is at least 10 to 20 times greater than any current variation that you expect on the virtual ground node.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to split a single rail to two rails is to use the [TLE2426](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tle2426.pdf) rail splitter IC. This has the advantage of being able to handle significant currents from either rail to the ground without becoming unbalanced and while using very little current from the supply. You can see a comparison of different methods [here](https://tangentsoft.net/elec/vgrounds.html).

[image]

As with all such active circuits, stability can be an issue. Be sure to look at the graph Fig 17 from the datasheet. For general purpose use, either have very little capacitance on the output or a lot.

[image]

---

As an aside, and this applies to any of the possible solutions (except @Jason's who shows you how to bias a single supply amplifier), note that if your input 20V voltage is connected to mains ground then the output and input of your amplifier will be referenced to about 10V above mains ground. This can cause various issues, including noise and shorting out the power supply. Just connecting a typical oscilloscope probe ground line to the input or output ground, for example, will short the supply if your 20V source has a mains ground on the negative side.

Many of these approaches will cause a massive thump at power-up if your application is for audio.

Comment: Thats a major no for me if there is a massive thump on power up.

Would you just suggest i bias my signal lines by 10v and leave the rails of the op amps at 20/0

Comment: You can inhibit the thump with a switch on the output. You would have to analyze the proposed bias circuit to see what happens, and possibly split capacitors to minimize the effect.

Comment: If thats the case would biasing the signal not be better?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

http://saroselectronics.com/single-supply-inverting-amplifier/

> Is there any real difference in a coupled output?

Depends on your application.